# How to fetch data inside a dynamic component in Next.js 13

Tags: next.js13, nextjs-dynamic-routing

I'm trying to fetch dynamic data from an api in Next.js 13 but the fetch function returned nothing.

```
import axios from "axios";

const baseURL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/articles/'
const frontURL = 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/'

async function getFeaturedArticles(slug) {

    const response = await axios({
      method: 'GET',
      url: baseURL + slug,
    });
    console(response.data)
    return response.data;
  }

export default function ArticleExpand({params}){
    const article = getFeaturedArticles(params.slug)
    console.log(article)
    return (
        <div>
           <div>
            {article.title}
           </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Neither `console(response.data)` nor `console.log(article)` returned something.

Comment: Try making it a fetch request I guess that might help in this server component.

Comment: I was able to solve it by making the functional component an async function. I think that is what I was missing.